# group plotly y-axis labels, but keep individual data lines

Tags: python, flask, plotly

I have a flask function that creates a timeline chart. I want to group the y-axis labels, but keep the individual data lines. How can I achieve this?

Here is my function:

```
def drawpipelinechart(ta='All'):
    table = pipeline_table().pipe(calc_fpfv_countdown)
    cols = [
        'ID',
        'PROTOCOL',
        'Quarter_Year',
        'Supplier_Selected',
        'TA',
        'PRODUCT'
    ]
    table = table[cols]
    table['End'] = pd.to_datetime(table['Quarter_Year'].str.split(
        ',').str[-1] + '-' + table['Quarter_Year'].str.split(',').str[0].str[-1] + '-01')
    table['Start'] = table['End'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3)
    table['link'] = table.apply(lambda x: f'<a href="/vo/editpipelinerecord/{x["ID"]}" target="_blank" class="nav-link" style="cursor: pointer;" target="_blank"></a>', axis=1)

    now = pd.Timestamp.now()
    end_date = now + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1) + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=18)
    table = table[(table['End'] > now) & (table['End'] <= end_date)]
    table = table[table['TA']==ta] if ta != 'All' else table
    table.loc[:, 'Supplier_Selected'] = table['Supplier_Selected'].fillna('Open')
    fig = px.timeline(table, x_start="Start", x_end="End", y="PROTOCOL", text='PROTOCOL',
                      color="Supplier_Selected", hover_name="PROTOCOL", template="simple_white",
                      labels={"Supplier_Selected": "Supplier"}, custom_data=['link'],
                      )
    
    fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")\
        .update_xaxes(
            showgrid=True,
            gridwidth=.5,
            gridcolor='lightgray',
            tickformat='%Y-Q%q',
            dtick='M3'
        )\
        .update_layout(
            margin=dict(t=100),
            xaxis=dict(side='top'),
            height=200+len(table['PROTOCOL'].unique())*40,
            autosize=True,
            yaxis_title=None,
        )\
        .update_traces(textposition='inside',
                       )

    # Add a horizontal line at each y-coordinate
    for y in table['PROTOCOL'].unique():
        fig.add_hline(y=y, line_dash="dot", line_width=1, line_color="gray")

    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    
    return graphJSON
```

This currently gives this:

[image]

I want to group the y-axis labels by the 'product' data column

Here is my desired result:

[image]

Update:

I have added a mapping to convert the 'protocols' to 'product' on the y-axis. Now I just have to figure out how to group them.

I added this:

```
yaxis=dict(
            title=None,
            tickmode='array',
            ticktext=table['PRODUCT'],
            tickvals=table['PROTOCOL'].unique()
        )
```

the code is now producing this:

[image]

any thoughts on how to group the y-axis labels from here?

Comment: Although not in ploltly's functionality, tickvals specifies the original index, and if there are two groups in the ticktext, the method is to combine the blank text and specify the group name in the text at the position you want to display. For example, here is an example of setting 2 group names for 5 indices. `fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=[0,1,2,3,4,5],ticktext=['','group1','','group2',''])`

Comment: @r-beginners sorry, i'm pretty new to plotly. I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. can you help with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no sample data for your question, I will answer the method I commented on by processing some of the [examples](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/#gantt-charts-and-timelines-with-plotlyexpress) in the reference. This method is to set the list of text you want to display at the position of the index you want to display with an empty text for the index of the y-axis. It cannot be centered when the number of indexes you want to group is an even number. plotly does not have the ability to handle this, so this is only a workaround.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource="Bob"),
    dict(Task="Job D", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource="Bob"),
    dict(Task="Job E", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource="Bob"),
    dict(Task="Job F", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource="Bob"),
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color='Resource')
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=[0,1,2,3,4,5],ticktext=['','group1','','','group2',''])
fig.show()
```

[image]